# CKEditor not fully uploading text

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, ckeditor

I've been having an issue using CKEditor (via PHP) where it doesn't save a full document to a SQL table. It then chucks a spaz when redirecting. 
For the most part it works really well. It seems to happen only for long text - as if it is limited to a certain character count (no restrictions are set at my end - but unsure if there is a limit set in CKEditor. I couldn't find any info about this anywhere).
The SQL table is a Longblob, so I believe that is capable of around 4GB of data. At first I thought it was due to images and the likes, but it turns out that plain text has the same issue.

So, my questions are:
1. Is there a limitation to the text being input by CKEditor?
2. Is there a form restriction on the  number of characters by default to a  tag?
3. Have I made a booboo?

```
//form blah
<textarea class='ckeditor' name='doc'></textarea>
//etc

//SQL query upload
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `docs` (`title`,`doc`,`date`,`author`,`category`) VALUES ('$title','$doc','$date','$author','$category')");
```

Comment: First of all, - don't use mysql_query... use pdo or mysqli driver.
In second, - it is posible, that query by it self have some limitation, but than you will retrieve an error...

There may be limitation for data, if you pass it by GET. But if you send it using post... it seems like there is no limitation i know. 
pre HTML4 attribute values were limited to 1024 chars. HTML4 changed to 64k chars which is SGMLs max value however:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/sgmldecl.html)

Comment: Is your form submitted with a method of GET or POST?

Comment: POST. I still haven't been able to resolve this.

Comment: Hi Rik!, did you find any solution to your problem, I am facing same issue, when I try to insert long text, or text with many images, it truncates some data and preserves some data, there is no issue of special characters, as it happens when I am pasting only converted images of my word file

Answer (score 0):

You data type in mysql is probably too small to hold a large amount of data. 
Try setting it to TEXT.

Comment: The table in MySQL is set as a Long Blob. And I have also tried Long Text as well. Both types end with the same result (truncated text)

Comment: can you paste the data in mysql directly without truncation?

Comment: Yes it goes straight into the table via paste and does not truncate any text

Comment: what about the post, does it show the full text before you try to save to the db?

Comment: You can enter the full text into the <textarea> and format it, add pics etc. Its only upon POST that the error occurs.